# How do I build a debian package whose sources include symbolic links outside of the source tree?

Tags: package, debian, symlink, tar

I have a project whose source includes symbolic links to other source trees (notably, the `CppUTest` framework). I need to build a debian package out of my project, but `dpkg-source` will not follow the symbolic links.

Digging further, I believe this is because the default behavior for `tar` is not to dereference symbolic links unless explicitly told to (with `-h`).

I was unable to find a way to pass this extra option to `tar` when building the debian source tarball.

So what am I doing wrong here? Is it possible to build a debian source tarball whose origin includes symbolic links? If so, how?

Comment: Given that you already got two answers about symlinks in deb packages, maybe emphasize that you already know how to do that, and that this is about building the `_orig.tgz` file.

Comment: @tripleee I have come back here 3 different times on 3 different days trying to figure out why you are down voting all the answers (I removed mine, but it was http://stackoverflow.com/a/15941526/117471 ) I think issue lies in the dual meanings of "build a debian package". I think the most common interpretation will be "create a debian package". However, the next to last sentence says "build a debian source tarball". That could be interpreted as "install a debian source tarball". The difference being producer vs. consumer.

Comment: Building a complete source package includes building an `orig.tar.gz`. The question makes it quite clear IMHO that this is where the problem lies, not in producing a .deb file, for which of course the answer is trivial, and irrelevant here.

Answer (score -1):

As read in this thread.. http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9752860&postcount=3

They can be included in the package just like normal files.

The details depend on the way you're doing the packaging, but using something like the following in debian/rules's `install' target should work:

```
ln -s /usr/share/whatever/file/you/want $(CURDIR)/debian/<pkgname>/usr/whatever/place/you/want/the/link
```

Everything inside debian/ will end up inside the .deb, including the symlinks you put there.

Comment: -1 This seems to answer a different question that the one that was asked.  Source tarball, not deb file.